# Rails Result with Association, Only Return Pre-Loaded Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent with many children. I preload a sub-set of children with an Active Record query. When I call `parent.children` I only want the sub-set to be returned rather triggering an N+1 query and returning all of the children.

```rb
parents = Parent.includes(:child).where(child: { attr: value })

parents.flat_map do |parent|
  parent.child # causes N+1
end
```

### Context / Use Case

I'm working on a capacity report for a booking system. If there's a pre-calculated `Occupancy` for a given day I want to show the `Occupancy` (child) stats, if not I want to show the pre-set for the `Resource` (parent).

```rb
class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :occupancies
end

class Occupancy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :resource
end

report_start_date = Date.today
report_end_date = report_start_date + 2.weeks
@resources = Resource.includes(:occupancies).where(occupancies: { date: report_start_date...report_end_date }).or(Resource.all).uniq
```

Within the `@resources` variable assignment above I want to pre-load occupancies for the reporting period (not outside the period) and I still want `Resources` that don't have `occupancies` within the reporting period.

So, although @Schwern's answer makes sense, it doesn't work for this use case - whereby I still need all the `Resources`.

Comment: I don't see `parent.children` just `parent.child`. It's clear you want to avoid n+1, but it's unclear what you want to do. Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish? Do you only want parents with children with certain attributes? Perhaps a simple example of some parents, children, and the result you'd like.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to add some context on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, but I'm still confused by your examples. 1) "*When I call `parent.children`...*" I still don't see `parent.children`. 2) Your Parent example is different from your Resource example. In the Parent example your `parents.flat_map` will produce an Array of Child objects. Your Resource example is the opposite, you get an Array of Resources (parents). Which is it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. That should do it, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all children which match a certain criteria, and their parents, in a single query, query the children and preload their parent.

```
children = Child
  .includes(:parent)
  .where(attr: value)
```

---

### UPDATE

If you want to only use associations which have already been eager loaded, you can check with [`loaded?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-loaded-3F).

```
@resources = Resource
  .includes(:occupancies)
  .where(occupancies: { date: report_start_date...report_end_date })
  .or(Resource.all)
  .uniq

@resources.find_each do |resource|
  puts resource.occupancies if resource.occupancies.loaded?
end
```